# How to identify if a page request is for a preview

Tags: http, web

When I paste my website link at a social network (Facebook or Twitter for example), the social network access my site to show a preview to the user.

I want to separate this access from real access at my reports, but to do this, I need to identify this cases.

This kind of access send any kind of information that is default for everysite that I can identify that this access is not a real user, but a robot?

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to identify those robots from their user-agent string.
For example, Twitter uses the [User-Agent of Twitterbot](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/guides/getting-started#crawling). And Facebook crawler identification is documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [User-Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) to do that.

```js
if (strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "Twitterbot") !== false)
   echo "TwitterBot";
else if (strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "facebookexternalhit") !== false)
   echo "Facebook";
else
   echo "regular user";
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler

Comment: I'm looking for a more generic way. My main "problem" is with cellphone SMS preview... There is a lot of different providers, and this if/else structure will be giant...

Comment: @BrunoCroysFelthes https://raw.githubusercontent.com/monperrus/crawler-user-agents/master/crawler-user-agents.json ?